# Starpoint Gemini 2 - Boarding - send more troops (second wave?)

Tags: starpoint-gemini-2

I'm having trouble to figure out how to send more troops to the ship I'm trying to board. What I mean is: **Is it possible to send a second wave of troops?**

I noticed that after unsuccessfully trying to board a ship, I still have a lot of hired men in my ship when I return to the base. So, probably it should be possible to make a second wave/try to board a ship, right?

Is there a place I should click or action to make? Because I tried to open the context menu and click on send troops button and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right side of the screen there will be a little icon that shows the number of your crew on the enemy ship and number of enemy crew along with 2 buttons the top one can send more over after the cool down is over as shown in this video the part you looking for starts at around 1:30 mark.

Comment: You saved my game! :) I thought I was lost but now I'm in control! That tip made me understand the troop transfer better. I was able to purchase a Wolverine and captured an Eldorado. After using my Eldorado to capture 4 other Eldorados, my ship is fully upgraded and kicking ...!